# More efficient way of accessing/rewriting uploaded images

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

At the moment we currently store image uploads in the following directory and format:

`/uploads/products/{product_id}.jpg`

However, we don't want this `uploads` directory to be shown publicly, and nor do we want to expose a product's unique ID, so we rewrite the requested image URLs as follows (using .htaccess and PHP):

`/images/products/{product_url}.jpg`

For reference, this corresponds to the product in question, such as:

`/products/{product_url}`

This has advantages of hiding the original upload folder as well as the unique ID of each product, by rewriting the ID to the corresponding URL of that product (which is obviously public knowledge).

The rewriting part of this works great; we process each request via .htaccess and then use PHP to query the database based on the ID given and retrieve the product's URL. However, as this process can be called numerous times per page, the amount of connections to the database can be ridiculous and slow. On certain pages, we end up re-connecting to the database 20+ times, once for each product image requested, which feels completely wrong and probably isn't very efficient at all.

Is there a better way to manage this process? We'd still like to keep rewriting the images to show the URL of the product rather than expose the product's ID or indeed `uploads` folder, if possible.

I've thought of generating a JSON file with a list of ID => URL pairs and then parse this upon image request instead of re-connecting and querying the database, but I'm not sure if this would be a valid, faster alternative?

(I've also contemplated persistent database connections but I'd rather not go down that route for now, if any other viable solutions exist instead.)

**EDIT:**

Some more information might help. We currently use .htaccess to rewrite the above image requests to a single file, `image.php`:

`RewriteRule ^images/products/(.*)$ image.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]`

Every time an image is requested, this file is called, checking that the URL is valid, and if so displays the real file located under `/uploads/products/{product_id}.jpg`.

So every time a browser encounters an `<img>` tag pointing to `/images/products/...` it starts the rewrite/database process each time the image is loaded, which is what I'm questioning the efficiency of really (and hence a new database connection each time too).

Comment: How often do the images change? You may send Cache-Control header and tell browser not to load that image for the next day or longer. Also consider the option of simply storing a copy of the uploaded image under the `/images/products/{product_url}.jpg` path and removing rewrite rules. It will require some additional space and cleanup work but it will be the fastest solution.

Comment: When you're fetching the products for your list, can't you just fetch the URL's in the same query?

Comment: I'd be curious to see some of your code. Why is it that you need to connect to the database 20+ times? If you're loading a products page why can't you get the image url at the same time as you fetch the other product information such as the ID?

Comment: ..another thing... why is the unique ID so secret?

Comment: Images themselves don't change that often, but product URLs can sometimes, hence the database query every time the image is requested. The 20+ connections happen only on a few pages, but this is because every image request is a new request, and so the database connection gets called each time. The rewrite rule maps to a separate `image.php` file that then handles this whole separate process.

Comment: Additionally, we use this same process not just for products but for other manufacturer images (mapping ID to a URL), etc. I suppose IDs could be exposed but at the same time we'd rather not show such information to competitors if possible, etc.